# extract values from varchar in redshift sql

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

SQL to fetch a value from varchar.I have a column elements as varchar in redshift as below

```
Id   elements
1 [{"name":"email","value":"abc@gmail.com","nodeName":"INPUT","type":"text"},{"name":"password","value":"*****","nodeName":"INPUT","type":"password"},{"name":"checkbox","value":null,"nodeName":"INPUT","type":"checkbox"}]
```

How do I select the value in this array above ie. abc@123

Answer (score 0):

If database of **MYSQL**, you should use

> json_extract

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    json_extract(JSON_DATA, '$[0].value') AS MAIL
FROM JSON_TABLE;
```

Result:

```
ID  MAIL 
1   "abc@gmail.com"
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/live/SQG30833

**Redshift** should probably use **json_extract_path_text** Function
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html